# show/hide html table columns using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to display a basic html table with controls to toggle showing/hiding of additional columns:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th class="col1">1a</th>
        <th class="col1">1b</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th class="col2">2a</th>
        <th class="col2">2b</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>100</td>
        <td class="col1">40</td>
        <td class="col1">60</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td class="col2">110</td>
        <td class="col2">90</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So Column 1 and Column 2 will be the only columns displayed by default - but when you click on the Column 1  I want 1a and 1b to toggle, and same with Column 2 with 2a and 2b.  I may end up with more columns and lots of rows - so any javascript looping approaches have been too slow to work with when I tested.

The only approach that seems to be fast enough is to set up some css like this:

```
table.hide1 .col1 { display: none; }
table.hide2 .col2 { display: none; }
table.hide3 .col3 { display: none; }

table.show1 .col1 { display: table-cell; }
table.show2 .col2 { display: table-cell; }
table.show3 .col3 { display: table-cell; }
```

And then set up onClick function calls on the table header cells that will trigger a toggle - and determine which css class to set "mytable" to that will create the toggle effect that I'm looking for.  Is there an easy way to set this up so that the code can work for n # of columns?

### Update

Here is what I came up with, works great - and really fast.  Let me know if you can think of ways to improve.

CSS

```
.col1 {display: none; }
.col2 {display: none; }
.col3 {display: none; }

table.show1 .col1 { display: table-cell; }
table.show2 .col2 { display: table-cell; }
table.show3 .col3 { display: table-cell; }
```

Javascript

```
function toggleColumn(n) {
    var currentClass = document.getElementById("mytable").className;
    if (currentClass.indexOf("show"+n) != -1) {
        document.getElementById("mytable").className = currentClass.replace("show"+n, "");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mytable").className += " " + "show"+n;
    }
}
```

And the html snippet:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
    <th onclick="toggleColumn(1)">Col 1 = A + B + C</th>
    <th class="col1">A</th>
    <th class="col1">B</th>
    <th class="col1">C</th>
    <th onclick="toggleColumn(2)">Col 2 = D + E + F</th>
    <th class="col2">D</th>
    <th class="col2">E</th>
    <th class="col2">F</th>
    <th onclick="toggleColumn(3)">Col 3 = G + H + I</th>
    <th class="col3">G</th>
    <th class="col3">H</th>
    <th class="col3">I</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="col1">10</td>
    <td class="col1">10</td>
    <td class="col1">0</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="col2">10</td>
    <td class="col2">8</td>
    <td class="col2">2</td>
    <td>20</td>
    <td class="col3">10</td>
    <td class="col3">8</td>
    <td class="col3">2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok so there doesn't seem to be another way to do this - but is there a way to do it so its a "sticky" toggle?  Right now, every time I show one column, the other column that was showing goes into the hide state.  I guess I have to add css rules to specifically handle every permutation??? I hope not...won't be fun if I'm dealing with 5 show/hide columns.

Comment: Hmm IE7 does not like the solution I posted.  I can get it to work with all the columns showing by default, but not with hiding by default...

Comment: You can add multiple classes: `table.className= 'show1 show3'` etc. I suspect the IE problem is that, as I mentioned, it does not support `display: table-cell`. I'd use classes like `hide` instead of `show`, so you only have to declare `table.hide1 col1 { display: none; }`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, that's pretty much it. In theory you could use [`visibility: collapse`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#dynamic-effects) on some `<col>`​s to do it, but browser support isn't all there.

To improve what you've got slightly, you could use `table-layout: fixed` on the `<table>` to allow the browser to use the simpler, faster and more predictable fixed-table-layout algorithm. You could also drop the `.show` rules as when a cell isn't made `display: none` by a `.hide` rule it will automatically be `display: table-cell`. Allowing table display to revert to default rather than setting it explicitly avoids problems in IE<8, where the table display values are not supported.

Comment: +1 for mentioning table-layout:fixed.  I've found that to be a huge help when displaying table formatted data.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the table-layout:fixed, but it didn't work in my case.  Dealing with a monster table with fluctuating column sizes which ends up needing table-layout:auto to look presentable.

Comment: That's a shame. Fixed tables can be much smoother than auto. (`fixed` doesn't necessarily mean all the columns have to have a fixed width, just that the widths don't depend on the amount of content in each cell.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510880/ie8-doesnt-apply-css-display-dynamically

Answer (score 35):

One line of code using jQuery:

```
$('td:nth-child(2)').hide();

// If your table has header(th), use this:
//$('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
```

Source: [Hide a Table Column with a Single line of jQuery code](http://www.devcurry.com/2009/07/hide-table-column-with-single-line-of.html)

Comment: Thanks! This selector also works great when you are trying to hide certain columns for a print style sheet.

Comment: After fiddling about with <col> tags, which don't appear to work in chrome, this worked perfectly

Comment: Keep in mind this will only work as expected for tables with an **equal number of cells per row**. If, for instance, you have some cells with `colspan="2"` and fewer cells in the remainder of that row, then `nth-child` will select (and in this case hide) cells from the wrong "column". For this reason, make sure you keep a note/comment of your column-hiding mechanism next to wherever the table will be edited, so that future editors don't break the layout.

Answer (score 15):

if you're looking for a simple column hide you can use the :nth-child selector as well.

```
#tableid tr td:nth-child(3),
#tableid tr th:nth-child(3) {
    display: none;
}
```

I use this with the @media tag sometimes to condense wider tables when the screen is too narrow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do to avoid what you are already doing, however, if you are building the table on the client with javascript, you can always add the style rules dynamically, so you can allow for any number of columns without cluttering up your css file with all those rules.  See http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript if you don't know how to do this.

Edit:
For your "sticky" toggle, you should just append class names rather than replacing them.  For instance, you can give it a class name of "hide2 hide3" etc.  I don't think you really need the "show" classes, since that would be the default.  Libraries like jQuery make this easy, but in the absence, a function like this might help:

```
var modifyClassName = function (elem, add, string) {
var s = (elem.className) ? elem.className : "";
var a = s.split(" ");
if (add) {
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      if (a[i] == string) {
          return;
          }
      }
  s += " " + string;
  }
else {
    s = "";
    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] != string)
            s += a[i] + " "; 
        }
    }
elem.className = s;
}
```

Comment: Your edit helped me a lot!  The sticky toggle is really easy now that I saw this!