# Hiding entire column of my table by adding a class on the heading col >> jQuery solution

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table where I would like to hide an entire column (3rth >> head+body) by simply applying a class named 'masked' to the heading col like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <th>aaa</th>
    <th class="masked">bbb</th>
    <th class="masked">ccc</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a1</td>
        <td>b1</td>
        <td>c1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a2</td>
        <td>b2</td>
        <td>c2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a3</td>
        <td>b3</td>
        <td>c3</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
```

The css:

```
.masked {
    display:none;
}
```

At this time, only the heading col is masked. How can I have the entire column to be masked?

See demo here: http://jsbin.com/axukob/1/

Thanks.

EDIT ---------------------

I'm OK with a jQuery solution because it seems to be difficult with only CSS. But it is important for me to keep the class added to the heading 'th'.

Please note that I may have more than 1 column to mask.

Comment: Give same class to third `tr`

Comment: Can't be done with pure CSS, you'll need javascript

Comment: I prefer only adding class at one single place >> to the heading.

Comment: Take a look at @Andy's comment then

Comment: Ok then I'll go for a javascript solution...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858339/show-hide-html-table-columns-using-css

Comment: td:nth-child(3){ display : none;} this will delete the 3rd column.. Try it

Comment: Guys, no way to do it with css but maybe anyhelp to do it with jQuery? I try with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're willing to use JS (which you will have to use), you can do this:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mBhB3/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var masked = $('.masked');
    $.each(masked, function() {
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $.each($('tr'), function() {
            $(this).find('td').eq(idx).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for all the rows in the table but the heading row is not hided. How to do the same for this heading row? Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore, your solution works only if only 1 row contains the class 'masked'. It does not work if I have multiple rows markes as masked. Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: @Bronzato: sorry, I wrote that script in a hurry. I've fixed it to work with multiple hidden columns. Also, the heading itself is hidden via CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Move the class to the table and add this style (renamed *mask-col-3* here):

```
<style type="text/css">
table.mask-col-3 th + th + th,
table.mask-col-3 td + td + td {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding below code in CSS will Hide the 3rd column in your table... Try it...

```
 td:nth-child(3){ display : none;}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/89/