# Firefox + Chrome table rendering issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, firefox

I am having an issue with displaying a table where the columns are displayed programmatically.

Following is the html code where this issue can be seen (and has confirmed its not the code behind affecting the rendering).

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>NUMER</th>                                      
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th align="center" style="display:block;">LOCATION</th>
    <th align="center" style="display:none;">1</th>
    <th align="center" style="display:block;">2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>BOB Jr</td>                                     
    <td align="center" style="display:block;"><input type="CheckBox" ID="updateLocation" runat="server" /></td>
    <td align="center" style="display:none;"><input type="CheckBox" ID="updateLocation" runat="server" /></td>
    <td align="center" style="display:block;"><input type="CheckBox" ID="updateLocation" runat="server" /></td>                                            
</tr>
```

This will display as the following on Chrome and Firefox:[image]

The style is added programmatically, which is clearly causing the issue however i was wondering if anyone has suggestions to resolving this issue?

The table columns have to be displayed programmatically as this functionality is user driven.

Also note this works fine on IE.

Comment: Not sure what attracted the downvote, appears a perfectly good question to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
 display:block
```

That is incompatible with tables.

You are looking for:

```
display:table-cell
```

That said, I suggest you give this question and answer a good read before proceeding, especially if you have to support older IE: [show/hide html table columns using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858339/show-hide-html-table-columns-using-css)

Comment: Thank you, this has been great help as i didnt think to use this css property. In terms of the browser I have tested on IE8, and this functions correctly, and i wont be supporting any older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this issue due to a very specific style in your HTML code. Removing the style="display:block" from the html (or from being programmatically inserted) will solve the issue. Refer the rectified HTML markup.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>NUMER</th>                                      
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th align="center" style="">LOCATION</th>
        <th align="center" style="display:none;">1</th>
        <th align="center" style="">2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>12345</td>
            <td>BOB Jr</td>                                     
            <td align="center" style=""><input type="CheckBox" id="updateLocation" runat="server"></td>
            <td align="center" style="display:none;"><input type="CheckBox" id="updateLocation" runat="server"></td>
            <td align="center" style=""><input type="CheckBox" id="updateLocation" runat="server"></td>                                            
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Praneeth, thats a good solutions however it just feels too hacky, but what i did try was what @KingCronus said which was to use display:table-cell. This has solved the issue as i can still continue using css to display the columns, which is what i pass programmatically and passing an empty string just doesnt feel right.